# react fetch header not set

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I am facing a problem. And the solutions that are accepted by the others, those don't work for me./

I have:

```
return await fetch(url, {
        method: httpMethod,
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'x-test':'try me',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(bodyObject)
    });
```

But, it seems like no header is set at all.

Cors-header is set, adding `mode:'cors'` makes no difference.

Am I missing something?

the request:

[image: Request]

`Accept` is empty and `Content-Type` nor `x-test` are nowhere to be found.

..

Edit

..

If i need to create new question, do tell me.

New request
[image: request2]

So I see that the header is set - thanks to liminal18!-. However, now i want to authorize to an AD.

so now I got:

```
async callUrl(url, httpMethod, bodyObject) {
    try {
        var requestObj = {
            method: httpMethod,
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'x-test':'try me',
                'Authorization': 'Basic Uk11bGxlc....'
            }
        };

        if (bodyObject !== undefined){
            requestObj.body = JSON.stringify(bodyObject);
        }

        return await fetch(url, requestObj);
    } catch(error){
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

But still get an 401.
I know this is not the clean solution for logging in, but just testing..

Comment: you might try if(bodyObject) and let javascript convert the object to a boolean. good job though glad you are making progress. is the 401  do to CORS? CORS can be a little tricky.

Comment: Your allow headers in the response is just authorization btw

Comment: options btw should not be returning a 401 maybe you are missing an auth header with the refresh token / access token?

Comment: well, the first call to the front-end prompts a basic authentication box, when logged in, the proxy continues to the desired site, that same-sites makes calls to the backend, through the same proxy. And I was hoping that I could use the same-credentials, something like 'credentials': 'include'. Hence, trying the authorization shizzle... :) need to set another header or so?

Comment: Take a look at the requests when logged in and see if there is an auth header. So many things could be wrong. Also I think there is a way to store an auth token maybe use redux and create a session reducer that stores the atuh token and then appends it requests as long ss the user is logged in. Kind of strange to realize I have never dealt with auth in react!

Comment: the `credential:same-origin` did the trick in Edge, so i am guessing that there needs to be set for other browsers... any thoughts?... we're getting there ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the request you captured is the correct request?
if you're using CORS there is an OPTIONS post to get the cors allowed methods before react will post/put which might be what you are looking at and not the actual post or put you intended. Where are the CORS headers set?

Comment: 100% sure. The response header has: Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*, maybe I am missing something, but it is only for a Get, does that make a difference?

Comment: on the request does the request method match the method sent to fetch?

Comment: also is this React.Js or React Native? keep in mind React Native does not use CORS.

Comment: is GET an allowed method on the server? you do have to specify both the methods and origins allowed.

Comment: yeah I just tried in console and my OPTIONS post lacked the headers however my GET request did have the headers. are you using chrome or firefox as your browser?

Comment: BTW a GET request can not have a body.